# how to check do low light image need restoration or not

Tags: python, image-processing, filter

I am trying to locate text from different types of images, and the challenge here is when i used dark images/night light images it is unable to detect text directly, and need image restoration.

currently i am using low light enhancement program separately and then using the same image for detecting text.
I want to detect text from 10 different images, of them some captured in low light and require enhancement. and i want to implement this part automatically enhance image only if it is have low-light feature, else the program should directly go to detect text.

image before light enhancement
[image: xx]

in the given image my approach unable to locate text. so i used light enhancement approach  and now resulting image is

[image: image after light enhacement]

with this image I am able to locate text.

Comment: look at the histogram of both images, the original one is shifted to the dark end, do statistical analysis to determine if the distribution is shifted

Comment: can i use some rage count  in histogram example (0-30) of (0-255) range , if it is grater than 50%, consider it as low light image?

Comment: there are statistical measurements to determine if a distribution is skewed